# VSCode/Git over 5k new changes in BranchA: commit, then switch to BranchB and untracked changes show up

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-untracked

I am in the process of moving over a massive project from and old Source Control(TFS).The scenario is that I have made changes and additions to over 5,000 files in BranchA. I finished my changes and committed and synced the changes. I then change to BranchB in VSCode and I get the over 5k warning. Those changes should not have carried to BranchB as they are solely intended for BranchA at the moment and will later be merged into BranchB when the time comes. Why would the files have not been tracked only to BranchA and is there any settings to resolve this.

While in BranchB `git reset --hard` does not appear to work with the amount of changes that it is detecting. The undo changes button in VSCode does nothing either.

Thanks!

Comment: Check if you really did commit those changes that are appearing as untracked changes. Most likely you thought you did, but you did not.

Comment: I did, that was actually the first thing I checked. I use visual studio team services and check the synced server for the commit.